# What does this % number in Google Analytics reflect?

Tags: google-analytics

In an In-Page Analytics report in Google Analytics, I see `6.7%` and `159 clicks` as displayed in this screenshot:

[image]

What does the percent number reflect? Is that the number of clicks vs. clicks to the whole site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google:

> These indicate the links users clicked. The numbers inside represent the percentage for the metric you chose in the Viewing menu.

Read more here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558864?hl=en